# background with pattern texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I tried it:

```
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
background.textureRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, calcadaWidth, winSize.height);
background.position = ccp(calcadaWidth * 0.5, winSize.height * 0.5);
ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
[background.texture setTexParameters:&params];
```

It works if the texture is regular gl size such as 64x64, 128x128...
My texture is 126x70, then, using this code I get some black space between repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2D uses OpenGL and one of the limitiation of OpenGL is that if you want a texture to repeat, it must be a power of two texture.

The black spaces you are getting is where OpenGL has padded your texture up to the next power of two.